# How To Parsing WhoIs Data Using Tokenizer

Tags: c#, tokenize

I am trying to make whois data grabber, I got the data in the below format.

```
Domain Name: google.com
Registry Domain ID: 2138514_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.markmonitor.com
Registrar URL: http://www.markmonitor.com
Updated Date: 2018-02-21T10:45:07-0800
Creation Date: 1997-09-15T00:00:00-0700
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2020-09-13T21:00:00-0700
Registrar: MarkMonitor, Inc.
Registrar IANA ID: 292
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abusecomplaints@markmonitor.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.2083895740
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited)
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited)
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited)
Domain Status: serverUpdateProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#serverUpdateProhibited)
Domain Status: serverTransferProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#serverTransferProhibited)
Domain Status: serverDeleteProhibited (https://www.icann.org/epp#serverDeleteProhibited)
Registrant Organization: Google LLC
Registrant State/Province: CA
Registrant Country: US
Admin Organization: Google LLC
Admin State/Province: CA
Admin Country: US
Tech Organization: Google LLC
Tech State/Province: CA
Tech Country: US
Name Server: ns1.google.com
Name Server: ns3.google.com
Name Server: ns4.google.com
Name Server: ns2.google.com
DNSSEC: unsigned
```

--
Now I am trying to parse the data using tokenizer but I don't understand how to use that tokenizer. Can any one give me an example code how to use tokenizer.

### https://github.com/flipbit/tokenizer

```
 var result = await WhoisClient.QueryAsync("google.com");
                string s = result.Raw;
               Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer();
                var pattern =@"{Domain Name: {WhoisRecord.Domain}";
                var result1 = tokenizer.Parse<WhoisRecord>(pattern, s);
                MessageBox.Show("Domain Name: " + result1.Domain);
```

--

Comment: So, all the data consists of many instances of `[key]<colon><space>[value]<new-line>`.  That seems pretty easy to parse.

Comment: Can you please be more specific.

Comment: Well, you could use a Regex that found the first instance of <colon><space> and used that to separate a line into two fields.  Or, you could just use `string.IndexOf(string)` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_) to find the separator and then use `string.SubString` twice to get the two parts.  Once you have the key and the value, shove them into a dictionary.

Comment: Unless you particularly _want_ to use Tokenizer, why not use [Whois](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Whois/) from the same author? Then it's as simple as this: `var whois = new WhoisLookup().Lookup("github.com"); 
Console.WriteLine(whois.Domain);`

Comment: Its working f9. I am just trying to learn tokenizer.